# Are We Allowed To Discuss Malware Creation

Tags: discussion, content, virus

I do not want to get in trouble  for it, so I decided to check here first. I have a code that I think is a legit virus, but on many forums I have been bashed for the discussion of malware creation. Would I get in any sort of trouble for posting about these things? Do you have a rule against it? I also know that many noobs come asking about how to create the (not) virus that just deletes a system file. I am not here to do that. My question is for purely research ans intellectual purposes.

Comment: There are some cases where I can understand such questions. However I general do not support such questions, because also bad guys could read my answer and I don't want to support them.

Comment: @rekire: Bad guys will have the weapons anyway. If they're discussed openly we can prepare our defenses.

Comment: In general, I'd say that the question is off-topic on SO, not because of the malware/virus application, but because you seem to be interested in asking what a piece of code does (or doesn't do).  There might be other SE sites where it would be more on-topic.

Comment: Could you refer me to one such site?

Comment: @James_Parsons I am not familiar enough with the scopes of these sites so I'd avoid asking there unless they say it is ok.  If you have the minimum rep, I'd suggest asking on their meta site.  IT Security (maybe).  Programmers (maybe).  Code Review (very unlikely).  And their could be others too.  But in general "discussion" is rarely on topic on all SE sites.  You have to ask a specific question and want a specific answer.